# How to create a macro for a templated function in c++

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, macros

I want to create a macro for a template function
something on the lines of

```
#define CHECK_MIN(T)(value, target) checkmin(T value, T target) \
checkmin<T>(T val, T target, __FUNCTION__, __LINE__)

template<typename T> checkmin(T val, T target, const char* functionName, long lineNumber)
{
    // Check if the val is less than target
    // Construct a std::string using the function name and line name
    // throw std:: exception passing the string constructed above.
}
```

I am not able to get the syntax to achieve this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by following way:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<typename T>
 void  checkmin(T val, T target, const char* functionName, long lineNumber)
 {
   // Check if the val is less than target
   // Construct a std::string using the function name and line name
   // throw std:: exception passing the string constructed above.
 }

#define CHECK_MIN(value, target)  \
 checkmin(value,target, __FUNCTION__, __LINE__);

int main() {
    /*Not using new in object definitions so I don't have to delete them afterwards since pointers don't stay in memory*/
    CHECK_MIN(5,6);

     return 0;
}
```